# libGDX Android SerializationException When Reading Json File

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, libgdx

I am trying to create a menu with scene2D and have it be compatible with android.

At the moment, the menu only has buttons since I am only figuring out how I should implement this.

The menu is working perfectly fine when I run the Desktop project, but when ever I run on android I get a serializationexception causing the app to crash :P.

If the desktop version can run without errors, then the json file is not the problem.

At first I was using libGDX 1.3.1 and though that was the problem. I tried 1.5.2 and 1.5.3 snapshot but still the same issue. Then I tried upgrading/updating my android versions and API's from 19 to 20 and still the same error.

Anyone know a solution to this or what could be causing this?

This is the logcat log:

```
01-13 16:39:21.523: V/AwesomePlayer(224): startAudioPlayer_l error status=0
01-13 16:39:50.474: W/NEXTREAMING(224): INF0:[APIs_Core.c 2314] nexPlayer_Close_Core Already      Closed(NEXPLAYER_ERROR_HAS_NO_EFFECT)
01-13 16:39:50.494: W/NEXTREAMING(224): INF0:[APIs_Core.c 3228] nexPlayer_Stop_Core Already  Stopped(NEXPLAYER_ERROR_HAS_NO_EFFECT)
01-13 16:39:50.494: W/NEXTREAMING(224): INF0:[APIs_Core.c 2314] nexPlayer_Close_Core Already Closed(NEXPLAYER_ERROR_HAS_NO_EFFECT)
01-13 16:39:50.494: W/NEXTREAMING(224): INF0:[APIs_Core.c 3228] nexPlayer_Stop_Core Already Stopped(NEXPLAYER_ERROR_HAS_NO_EFFECT)
01-13 16:39:50.494: W/NEXTREAMING(224): INF0:[APIs_Core.c 2314] nexPlayer_Close_Core Already Closed(NEXPLAYER_ERROR_HAS_NO_EFFECT)
01-13 16:39:50.805: E/AndroidRuntime(18220): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: menus/ui/menuSkin.json
01-13 16:39:50.805: E/AndroidRuntime(18220): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: menus/ui/menuSkin.json
```

Edit: Upon trying to run it again, the same exception and log as above occured, but now there is some extra information.

```
01-13 19:52:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:683)
01-13 19:52:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:873)
01-13 19:52:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:834)
01-13 19:52:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:873)
01-13 19:52:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(20675):    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:681)
```

Here is how I retrieve the JSon file in my code

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("menus/ui/menuSkin.json"), texture);
```

Here is the Json file if you need it:

```
{   
   "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color":{
  "white": {"r":1, "g":1, "b":1, "a":1},
  "black": {"r":0, "g":0, "b":0, "a":1},
  "red": {"r":1, "g":0, "b":0, "a":1},
  "green": {"r":0, "g":1, "b":0, "a":1},
  "blue": {"r":0, "g":0, "b":1, "a":1}
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont":{
  "black32": {"file":"menus/fonts/black32.fnt"}
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle":{
  "default": {"up":"buttonPlay.up","down":"buttonPlay.down","font":"black32"}    
},
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
   "default": {"font": "black32", "fontColor": "red"}
}


}
```

I use Eclipse by the way.

I run/test my android applications on my phone, an LG Motion.

Edit:

Did a few debugs and logging.
When I logged Gdx.files.internal("menus/ui/menuSkin.json").exists()) it returned true in the log cat.

I also tried using external, local, and classpath instead of internal but no dough. Haven't found much in the documentations either.

Comment: I checked the source, and any IOException on the file will bubble up as a SerializationException in the Json class. Might want to check your file structure. Maybe you have it set up correctly on desktop but not on your Android build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem.

The problem was this:

"black32": {"file":"menus/fonts/black32.fnt"}

black32.fnt should have been Black32.fnt

I had no idea that files had to be case sensitive on Android. I didn't realise that this was the problem because...well 1. It never said the font file was the problem, and 2. the desktop version worked fine.

I resolved this issue thanks to sickmartian from the libGDX forums

I also want to thank Tenfour04 for their input.